# Trying to add google maps to a Vaadin view

Tags: java, google-maps, vaadin

I'm trying to use the [Vaadin GoogleMaps plugin](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/googlemaps-add-on) on our web application to show a small window with Google maps. I have this:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private LatLon mapMarkerlatLon;
private GoogleMapMarker googleMapMarker;
private final String apiKey = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<ourKey>=initMap";

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    //googleMap = new GoogleMap(apiKey, null, null);
    //As suggested:
    googleMap = new GoogleMap(apiKey, null, "english");         

    mapMarkerlatLon = new LatLon(0,0);
    googleMap.setCenter(mapMarkerlatLon);
    googleMapMarker = new GoogleMapMarker("Tal", mapMarkerlatLon, false);
    googleMap.addMarker(googleMapMarker);
    initializeViewContent();
}
```

A bit further down my class..

```
protected CssLayout initializeViewContent() {
    CssLayout sideBarLayout = new CssLayout();
    sideBarLayout.addStyleName("sidebar");
    /* ... */
    sideBarLayout.addComponent(googleMap);
    return sideBarLayout;
}
```

There's more stuff around the class,but basically this is the "important" bit. When I load the page, I got this:

[image]

More or less, translated to english, it says "An error occured. This webpage did not load Google Maps correctly. Discover the technical details on the Javascript console."

EDITED: Firfeox Console is as empyt as my knowledge of this topic.
**Chrome's console is telling me about a missing keyMapError.**

I've tried changin the key format to:

- {ourKey}
- {ourKey}=initMap
- key={ourKey}=initMap

And, well, I'm getting tired of playing with combinatory. The key works, as it was given to me with a small demo that works flawlessly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you load the page with the javascript console open? I don't think the console messages are kept unless the console is already open.

Comment: When I used this map I passed in the language. -->GoogleMap googleMap = new GoogleMap(googleAPIKey, null, "english");

Comment: @Chris M: Yeah, I did left that open. There's nothing to see there, nor in the server logs, nor in anything.

Comment: Darn, seems it did not saved the whole comment: i tried the "english" thing, and initially worked. It seems there is some extra trouble with the key, as it worked for a little bit, then failed again. There's any kind of specific formatting for using the key?